# Use PEAR along with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been using codeigniter from last 7 months. So how can i use PEAR libraries in codeigniter?

Which are the useful PEAR libraries that can be used in codeigniter?

Comment: review this link https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/PEAR-integration

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this ...